# Why can't I install bc on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sudo, raspberry-pi, source, bc

When I try to run the command `sudo apt-get install bc` I get the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package munin-memcached is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'bc' has no installation candidate
```

I did some research and was told that I could fix this problem by running `sudo apt-get update` which I did, followed by `sudo apt-get -f install` and then finally `sudo apt-get install bc` once again. However I still get the same error message.

Content of my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Ya they're the ones who told me to run `sudo apt-get update` to try fixing my problem. However, that didn't work.

Comment: `bc`, arm64 is available as a package for Ubuntu versions 14.04 and 16.04   http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bc&searchon=names

Comment: I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi and not using Ubuntu.

Comment: Works for me. /etc/debian_version is 8.5, from repo jessie/main.

Comment: The [Debian jessie documents](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/arm64/bc/download) only have the `bc` package for ARMv8. The Pi is ARMv6, Pi 2 is ARMv7 and Pi 3 is ARMv8. So I don't think the bc package is available from the official Debian repos for the Pi or Pi 2. You might need to find compile from source or find a repo that has the ARMv6 version of `bc`.

Comment: @Munir Sorry but this is my first time working with Linux or a Raspberry Pi. Are you saying that I can't install `bc` on my board?

Comment: I just installed bc ok on a pi 3, as mentioned above,  and now a pi 2 as well with no trouble. Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for which repository you have chosen (add it to your POST). You might try clearing a corrupt cache, `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: Ya the problem is with my `sources.list` file. I've changed it so many times because I tried following what other forums told me and now I have no idea what to put there. Could you tell me what you have on yours?

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse No, that's not what I meant. I am saying that you are not using the correct repos to install it. You just need to find the right repo that provides `bc` for the Pi, probably by looking at the original source list that comes with Raspbian.

Comment: @Munir I don't know what the correct repos are. I've tried to change my `soures.list` file so that I could have the correct repos but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: @meuh Can you tell me what it is that I am missing?

Comment: @IsabelAlphonse Can you please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question? That will help others identify what is missing.

Comment: @Munir I've added the content of my `sources. list` file. I got those lines from the Raspberry Pi website.